# "Button_Press_Event" Coordinates Being Called Before I Actually Click

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, click

I am plotting a fits image of a field of stars. I am then displaying circular apertures across the image on sufficiently bright stars. Next, I am trying to click on the star that I am interested in, and getting the brightness measurement out of the nearest circle. Finally, I want to use that brightness measurement for other calculations.

My problem is that the variable I declare to store the x,y coordinates of my click ("coords") seems to be getting called before I actually click, resulting in an empty array and errors.

A co-worker sent it to me many months ago, and once upon a time it worked flawlessly. But it seems that it's stopped working. It may be a result of updating some libraries/modules, but I can't be sure.

I have tried various combinations, including declaring "coords" in other function, in other locations, etc. I have tried changing the order of certain lines to perhaps get "coords" to be called later. I've also tried writing the code from the ground up, and have had many of the same errors. Because this specific code once worked, I attach it instead of my attempts.

To be honest, I don't fully understand the code, as I didn't write it. As a result, I don't understand what is being called when, or what any changes I've made actually do.

```
def plot_image(file, vmin=5, vmax=99, threshold=5, radius=25):

    hdu=fits.open(file)
    image = hdu[0].data
    exptime = hdu[0].header['EXPTIME']
    band = hdu[0].header['FILTERS']
    airmass = hdu[0].header['AIRMASS']
    readnoise = hdu[0].header['RN_01']
    gain = hdu[0].header['GAIN_01']
    obj = hdu[0].header['OBJECT']

    sub = image[1500:2000,1500:2000]

    bkg_sigma = mad_std(sub)

    mean, median, std = sigma_clipped_stats(sub, sigma=3.0, maxiters=5)

    daofind = photutils.DAOStarFinder(fwhm=2., threshold=threshold*bkg_sigma)  
    sources = daofind(sub - median) 

    positions = (sources['xcentroid'], sources['ycentroid'])
    apertures = photutils.CircularAperture(positions, r=radius)
    phot_table = photutils.aperture_photometry(sub - median, apertures)

    pix = select(image, apertures)
    print(pix)

    if len(pix) == 2 or len(coords) == 2:
        distance = np.sqrt((np.array(phot_table['xcenter'])-pix[0])**2 + (np.array(phot_table['ycenter'])-pix[1])**2)
        star = np.argmin(dist)
        counts = phot_table[star]['aperture_sum']
        fluxfile = open('testfile.txt')

        signal = (counts * gain) / exptime
        err = np.sqrt(counts*gain + (readnoise**2*np.pi*radius**2))
    else:
        print('Pix length = 0')

def select(image, apertures, vmin = 5, vmax = 99):

    global coords
    coords = []

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (9,9))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.imshow(image, cmap  = 'gist_gray_r', origin='lower', vmin = np.percentile(image, vmin), vmax = np.percentile(image, vmax), interpolation='none')
    apertures.plot(color='blue', lw=1.5, alpha=0.5, ax = ax)
    ax.set_title('Hello')#label='Object: '+obj+'\nFilter: '+band)

    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    plt.show()  

    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
    if None in coords:
        return [np.nan,np.nan]
    else:
        return np.round(coords)

def onclick(event):

    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    global coords
    coords = [x, y]

    plt.close()
    return 

def closeonclick(event):
    print('Close On Click')
    plt.close()
    return
```

Expected Result: The image is displayed with blue apertures overlaid. Then, I click on the desired star and the coordinates I click are stored to "coords" and printed to the console. The window displaying the image is closed alongside the previous step, as well. Finally, using those coordinates, it finds the nearest aperture and does some science with the resulting brightness.

Actual Result: "coords" is immediately printed (an empty list). Immediately after, the image is displayed. Clicking it does nothing. It doesn't change the value of "coords", nothing else is printed, nor does the window close.

Answer (score 0):

I'll come back and delete this if it isn't right (I'd comment if I had the reputation), but it looks like you have to define a global variable outside any functions first, then use the keyword before the variable name inside a function to change its scope. Try moving "coords = []" outside your functions (the list will no longer be empty after the first call to "onclick", but each new click should replace the coordinates so it shouldn't be an issue).

Ref: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword